# Diploma for blue card in Germany

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I have received a job offer in Germany, I from Brazil, I would like to know if my diploma affects my application, since it is a 2 and half year diploma well recognized in Brazil of formal education (tertiary education).

It is an IT Degree which normally is compared to an Associate Degree outside Brazil.

Is this a problem, or this diploma is eligible for me to work in Germany?

By the way, I am applying for a blue card.

Comment: Not exactly duplicates but related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/do-i-need-a-degree-in-it-to-apply-for-an-eu-blue-card-as-a-software-engineer-or and http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2938/whats-my-degree-worth-in-germany?rq=1

Comment: Could you post the name of your diploma (e.g. "Bacharel em Letras")? I couldn't see anything just named "diploma" in the [official database](http://anabin.kmk.org/anabin-datenbank.html). The only short qualifications in the list (named "tecnólogo") do *not* qualify for a blue card. Note that the database does not contain all qualifications. In that case you need to go through the assessment process to check the eligibility.

Comment: Hi @neo, the name is "Tecnologo em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas". Where did you see that it does not qualify? Thanks.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda Could you please at this to do the question text as this is important to answer the question. Comments are volatile.

Comment: So @user6682, did you apply for the blue card? how did it go?

Comment: how your application process finished, did you able to get blue card?

Answer (score 7):

Your degree *Tecnólogo em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas* listed in the [Anabin database](http://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/hochschulabschluesse.html), which is used to compare foreign degrees to German ones. This database is checked by immigration officers when you apply for a blue card.

For your degree it lists the equivalence class

> Bedingt vergleichbar: Bakkalaureus/Bachelor 3j

which means it's only partially comparable to a German 3 year Bachelor.

According to the [German residence act, § 18a Abs. 1 Nr. 1](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0244) an applicant can only get a blue card if

> he
>
> a)  holds a German or a foreign higher education qualification which is **recognised or otherwise comparable to a German higher education qualification**

(Emphasis mine). A partly comparable degree is not enough by the words of the law.

This interpretation of the law is [shared by the Federal Minstry of the Interior](http://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Themen/MigrationIntegration/Auslaender/hochqualifiziertenrichtlinie.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) and laid down in the various administrative regulations, e.g [the Baden-Württemberg one](https://im.baden-wuerttemberg.de/fileadmin/redaktion/m-im/intern/dateien/pdf/VwV-AuslR-IM_ABSCHNITT_C_28042015.pdf).

Additionally to the degree, the school or university needs to be listed in the database as "H+" to recognize the degree.

Any applicant can send their degree to [ZAB](http://www.kmk.org/information-in-english/statement_of_comparability_for_foreign_higher_education_qualifications.html) first, which (for a fee) will compare the individual case to the German education system and issue an official statement.

Even if the path to a blue card is not open, it is of course still possible to get a work permit with less requirements (but it's harder to obtain them).

Comment: Interestingly enough is the fact that there's an "or" in  the very end of term a).

Which sounds it is still possible get a blue-card to work as a High Skilled Professional, since I have more than 5 years of experience. Well let's see how things go. I will be applying for it in the next weeks, I will also answer the question, once I have the response.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda I'm not sure why I even included that option in the excerpt as the "statuary instrument" from sub-section 2 has never been created. So at the moment, having a comparable university degree is the only option.

Comment: What do you mean by this, so this clause is no valid? They will not count the experience?

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda Yes. The clause says that the specific rules for experience need to be created but up until now they weren't. So at the moment only the degree but not experience counts for the blue card. Note that for other work permits it works a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through exactly this situation (except that my degree has a 3 years duration) and know many people in the same situation. The informations below are based on successful experience on getting a work visa, as well as observing other people's experiences.

When has one has a *técnologo* there is absolutely no need to contact the ZAB for degree equivalence.

All one has to do is ask the company to fill in some forms and send them to the ZAV, which handles and approves (or not) the hiring of foreigners. In case of approval, ZAV will issue a document which basically says that the person can be hired as a specialist.

This "specialist visa" doesn't care about degrees, one can get it having only some experience in the field.

It is also worth noting that folks with *técnologo* degree will not receive the Blue Card, only the Work Visa.