# Associate degree for EU Blue card in Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have received a job offer in Germany, I from Brazil, but I live now in Czech Republic, I have a working Visa here.

I would like to know if my diploma affects my application, since it is a 2 and half year diploma well recognized in Brazil of formal education.

It is an IT Degree which normally is compared to an Associate Degree out of Brazil.

Is this a problem, or this diploma is eligible for me to work in Germany?

PS: I know there is a question exactly like this. But is from 2015.

And I read it in the official website that is possible to get the Blue Card with at least 5 years of experience.

Here is the link for reference: http://www.eu-bluecard.com/eu-blue-card-germany/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Diploma for blue card in Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/diploma-for-blue-card-in-germany) Nothing changed from 2015. Also, you do not necessarily need a Diploma to work in Germany, see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/is-it-true-that-you-dont-need-a-degree-to-work-as-an-it-specialist-in-germany/11511#11511, it applies to all, not only IT specialists.

Comment: The first question to ask whenever someone writes "a job offer in Germany" is simply: Contract work (self-employed?) or becoming an employee of the Germany company. These will be very different rules.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I'm going after my german work permit here from Brazil.

I've contacted the consulate in Sao Paulo and they answered, by e-mail, that associate degrees (técnologo, in Brazil) doesn't qualify for the Blue Card in Germany.

Instead, you have to apply for the regular work visa. Therefore, your employer is required to send your documents and a few forms to the ZAV (https://www3.arbeitsagentur.de/web/content/DE/service/Ueberuns/WeitereDienststellen/ZentraleAuslandsundFachvermittlung/index.htm).

Also, you should check if your degree and institution area listed in the ANABIN database (https://anabin.kmk.org/anabin.html). In case it isn't, you most likely would need to get the ZAB equivalency (https://www.kmk.org/zab/central-office-for-foreign-education/certificate-of-equivalence.html) before applying for the ZAV.