# German bluecard vs work permit in context of education

Tags: germany, family, blue-card

I looked this question: [Blue Card vs Work Permit for IT Specialists](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/blue-card-vs-work-permit-for-it-specialists) but have some additional questions.

I try find job in Germany as software developer. I have master degree as physicist. Does it make impossible getting bluecard because of education? Or years of work experience can compensate that my master degree don't sound like "computer science"?

Can it help that at university we had a lot computer science disciplines because supposed that we should be able write software for processing results of our experiments? For example image processing, numerical methods, writing software for working with hardware such as oscilloscope.

For example IT disciplines from my both diplomas (bachelor and master):

- "Programming"
- "Operating systems and programming languages"
- "Software systems"
- "Network technologies"
- "Information Systems"
- "Computer technology in physics"
- "Computer simulation of processes in solids"
- "Multidimensional data analysis in physical condensed states"
- "Virtual instruments in physics"
- "The use of information technology in physical research"
- "Computational physics"
- "Numerical methods and mathematical modeling"
- "Radio Physics and Electronics"

Almost for all this disciplines we wrote software with C, Python, Pascal or in Matlab. And i have two diplomas related with neural networks data processing. Can i prove that my education related enough with my speciality?

In case if i don't get bluecard, can it impact on my wife work perspectives? As i know with my bluecard my wife immediately get work permit.

If i get only work permit, is my wife able to work in Germany? Can she have any problems with arrival and living in Germany? Or she can immediately arrive and live but without work permit?

Comment: Without a Blue Card, your wife can live with you. Depending on what type of work given in the application may or not be granted. So can try, but it may not be granted. The guidelines are not very clear about this, thus only as comment and not an answer.

Comment: As to your main question the Blue Card is base on your work contract and salary. So the type of job want you for will probably be the determinating factor, assuming your degrees are recognized in the ANABIN database. This is a assumption, thus as comment.