# Is a graduate degree required to get a blue card in Germany?

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card

I know this has been asked before, but I'd like to know if anything has changed since. Is it still required to have a graduate degree to get a German Blue Card? I'm from India, I'm sure that's required information.

Do all kinds of work permits require a graduate degree? I'm a (to be) drop out (dropping out for personal reasons) seeking a job in Germany, and I've gotten responses from quite a few companies. I'm afraid that my lack of degree is going to be a hindrance.

Comment: I'm not seeing that as a requirement [here](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/BuergerDrittstaat/BlaueKarte/blaue-karte-node.html) on a German government site. It just says an equivalent-to-German higher education degree. There is a link to the Anabin site where you can look up your degree as well. You have to apply for a regular work permit first anyway, then apply for the card once you're in Germany.

Comment: Please see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11511/13223 for related info

Answer (score 1):

You need a Bachelor's (undergrad) degree, not a Masters degree. From the BAMF website:

> Applicants must provide proof of having completed higher education. If the higher education qualification was not acquired in Germany, it must either be recognised or be comparable to a German higher education qualification.