# Is my Bachelor's degree recognised in Germany if anabin lists my university but not the course?

Tags: germany, study

I am looking to do my Master's degree in Germany and I checked the anabin database to see if my certificate will be recognised by German universities. I have found that my university is listed as H+ (which I assume is a good sign) but my Bachelor's course is not listed in the database. Does that mean that my certificate is not recognised in Germany? If so, what do I have to do get it recognised?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eligible for Germany bluecard with a non-anabin-listed degree and a H+/- university?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/eligible-for-germany-bluecard-with-a-non-anabin-listed-degree-and-a-h-univers)

Answer (score 4):

> Die Auflistung der erfassten Abschlüsse erhebt keinen Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit.

Translated:

> The list of recognized degrees does not claim to be complete.

So your degree not being in the list only means... it's not in the list because the list is not complete. Universities changes their coursework all the time and the database has no means to keep up with courses. **"H+" means your university is recognized as such in your country and is recognized as a university by Germany as well. That's definitely a good thing, your bachelor degree will be recognized.**

However, please note that in Germany, certain Master certifications need a *specific* bachelor degree (for example you cannot apply for a Master of Laws when your bachelor was in fine arts). So you will need to take your *specific* information and find out.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my experience, the German Embassy asked for a [Statement of Comparability for Foreign Higher Education Qualifications](https://www.kmk.org/kmk/information-in-english/statement-of-comparability-for-foreign-higher-education-qualifications.html) from the Zentralstelle für ausländisches Bildungswesen(ZAB) as only my University (H+) was listed in the ANABIN Database and not my degree under that University. ZAB are also maintaining the ANABIN database.

Sadly on my ZAB application, I learned that an "H+" University doesn't necessarily means that all degrees offered in that university is equivalent to a German degree.