# How to search Anabin website to comply with Germany work visa requirement?

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit, residence-cards

I struggle to find information on how to utilize the search functions in Anabin's website in order to produce the result of my University name and my degree in one search functions. I graduated with a Bachelor of Business Administration in International Trade. I can find my university name, University of Central Arkansas, Conway, USA. it's H+ but there's only 2 degrees listed there. When I search based on majors, there's only International Business and not International Trade. Is it possible to get a result of the search to show both my university and degrees earn? Can anyone help provide me with the guidance on how to do this as I need to send screenshot of this to the embassy. Thanks much!!!

Comment: It's very likely that your degree hasn't been certified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my Bachelor's degree recognised in Germany if anabin lists my university but not the course?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12141/is-my-bachelors-degree-recognised-in-germany-if-anabin-lists-my-university-but)

Comment: You might also review this thread: _https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/eligible-for-germany-bluecard-with-a-non-anabin-listed-degree-and-a-h-univers?rq=1_