# Will my Bachelor's degree be recognized if it's missing in the Anabin database?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, eu, blue-card

So I have just submitted my documents for EU blue card in Germany. I hold a Bachelor's of Science degree from a H+ Doctoral university from USA. But my major - Computer Engineering is not in the Anabin database. So right now I'm a bit worried about the outcome. The officer on the receiving end said that everything seemed to be in order.

I need advice now. Should I submit my documents through ZAB immediately or should I wait for the result? Provided that the contract starts in a month.

Comment: Don't they need certification that the education is equivalent before they'll approve the card?

Comment: Do they? I'm not sure, the officer didn't say anything. So I wonder if that is required of me or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eligible for Germany bluecard with a non-anabin-listed degree and a H+/- university?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/eligible-for-germany-bluecard-with-a-non-anabin-listed-degree-and-a-h-univers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what happened to me:
I went to the embassy where they didn't ask me about my diploma directly, just asked if its H+ or not. And since I had the contract I received the Visa really fast. Now thats where it gets fuzzy. I only got the visa for 6 months, according to the embassy - that time is sufficient enough to get the blue card.

Once I arrived to Germany I started the ZAB diploma confirmation, which took about 3 weeks, and I have also applied for the blue card which I will probably get in a month or so.

Conclusion:
The embassy is not in charge of blue card issuance, but rather give visa straight away for you to start working right away (which was very helpful). ZAB - 200 euro, Blue card - 110 euro. 2 months of waiting but at least I already started working. Hope any of that helps

Comment: Hi Dan, I got a job offer in Germany but my university is not H+, its H+/-, and my course is not listed, do you have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: @HassanAliSalem Would it be possible to share what you ended up doing? as I'm in a similar situation but my university is H+

Comment: Hello Islam, I have applied for a statement of comparability, you can check this link: https://www.kmk.org/zab/central-office-for-foreign-education/statement-of-comparability-for-foreign-higher-education-qualifications.html

Comment: Thank you Hassan for the reply, did you finish this step before going to the German embassy or after going to Germany but before applying for the residency permit? How much time did this step take you since you applied until you received the statement?

Comment: @HassanAliSalem CC

Comment: It took me less than 2 weeks, because I was applying for a blue card. you should have these documents before going to the embassy, but you can apply and if you dont have them you can tell the embassy that you have applied and you will bring them when they are ready