# Do I need a recognized university degree to get a visa to work as developer in Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit

I work as a developer in the Middle East (Lebanon).
Lately, I got a job offer and a contract from a great company in Germany, but I found that my university degree is not recognized (actually its H+/-, that means: no clear statement about the university degree) so I looked into it and found that I need to apply for recognition, but the problem is, it might take about 3 months, which I don't have!.

So I am wondering if I can apply for the visa using the job contract and my unrecognized degree, or it most probably will be rejected?

---

Update:

So after contacting the ZAB service in Germany, I got the recognition in 1 week! because I was applying for a Blue card. Other applications might take 3 months but for the blue card, it is one to two weeks.
So make sure to mention that you are recognizing your degrees for a blue card application.

Also, you cannot apply for a blue card without a recognized degree.

I got the visa after 4 months of the application!
But here in Germany, the processes are very complicated and not well organized. So I applied for a family reunion visa for my family and after 7 months, I was checking and they don't know anything about the application and no one is helping. So for me till now it is a bad experience here.

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true that you don't need a degree to work as an "IT specialist" in Germany? What exactly classifies as "IT specialist" in this context?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/is-it-true-that-you-dont-need-a-degree-to-work-as-an-it-specialist-in-germany)

Comment: @AndreySapegin Not quite a duplicate.  The linked question asks "do I need a degree", this question asks "do I need a recognized degree".

Comment: if the degree is not recognised in Germany, one will be treated as having no degree, which is the same in the end.

Comment: @Hassan, looks like some time has passed since you asked the question. It would be great if you could share if you managed to get the visa or not. Any tips?

Comment: @WinstonJude I have updated the answer. Thank you for pinging me :)

Answer (score 4):

The relevant rules can be found on the website of the *Bundesargentur für Arbeit*.  A good general summary can be found [here](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/en/german-labour-market), but the specific rules are [here](https://con.arbeitsagentur.de/prod/apok/ct/dam/download/documents/dok_ba014306.pdf).  (The second link is more likely to suffer link rot in future.)

There are a number of different grounds for being granted a visa.  The two most relevant ones are:

> - Foreigners that practise a shortage occupation and whose salary is at least
>     52 per cent of the annual contribution assessment ceiling for the statutory
>     pension fund 2020 = 43,056 Euro
> - Foreigners with a recognised foreign university degree or one that is
>     comparable to a German university degree

Unfortunately your degree has not been recognized or declared comparable to a German university degree.  (According to [this answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11540/14680) the degree has to be recognized by ZAB - although that was in the context of Blue Card rather than direct German visa.)

The [current list](https://con.arbeitsagentur.de/prod/apok/ct/dam/download/documents/whitelist_ba015790.pdf) of shortage occupations lists "software developer" at the "specialist" level.  "Specialist" level means:

> Specialist - is assigned to occupations that require special knowledge
>   and special skills, which usually require a master or technician training or an equivalent technical college or university degree.

Note that they do *not* say that it has to be a *recognized* degree, just that your employer was looking for a graduate rather than a school leaver.

**Conclusion:**

I believe you can obtain a German work visa even though your specific degree has not been recognized.  The fact that your position is for a software developer where a degree is required should be enough.  Your salary also needs to be at least 40,000€ (precise figure above).

I would recommend

1. Apply for visa
2. Apply for your degree to be recognized
3. When that has happened, you can apply for a Blue Card

Comment: This doesn't feel a well structured answer.  If someone could edit it into better shape, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Must at least or must both entries be true?

Comment: @gerrit At least one must be true (there are a number of others which are not relevant to the OP).  I will clarify

Comment: Nice answer, but the conclusion seems to be incorrect. I.e., the decision might not depend on salary that much as far as I understood from the cited documents.

Comment: @AndreySapegin You can get a visa as a practitioner of a shortage occupation if you earn at least €40k.  If you don't earn that, you can't get the visa (on those grounds) - but it doesn't matter if you are on €40k or €140k.  Beyond that, what do you mean by "might not depend on salary that much".

Comment: I have went through the linked document (https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/datei/dok_ba014306.pdf), having a salary of 52% more than average is JUST ONE OF MULTIPLE options there. Other options are: foreigners with a recognised foreign university degree; specialists of  a  company  established  in Germany with company-specific specialist knowledge; etc. etc. So the conclusion in current form is misleading. The salary is only one of many options.

Comment: @AndreySapegin As I said, "There are a number of different grounds for being granted a visa."  and "The two most relevant ones are".  My answer was addressed to the circumstances of the OP; I believe it was not misleading *for them*.  If you can see a way to generalize my answer so that it is more useful for other readers, please propose an edit, and ping me in the comments so I can approve it.

Comment: Sorry, I've rejected that edit.  It made the answer less applicable to the OP, and didn't (I think) make it more generally true.  (Also, there's no need to wait until one has entered Germany in order to apply for the degree to be recognized.