# Relocate to Germany. Anabin. Statement of Comparability for Foreign Higher Education Qualifications

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card, ukraine

The question is about the relocation to Germany from Ukraine.

- I've got a contract from the German company with enough salary to get a Blue Card.
- I collected all the necessary documents.
- The problem is that: I got a diploma in 2017 and there is the old name of my specialty in Anabin (before 2010) database and it looks like:
  https://anabin.kmk.org/index.php?eID=user_anabin_abschluesse&conf=abschluesse&uid=14794
  OR
  https://anabin.kmk.org/index.php?eID=user_anabin_abschluesse&conf=abschluesse&uid=13865

But in 2010 it was renamed according to the document:
https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/rada/show/v1067290-10

And now the name is: 
"inzheneriia prohramnoho zabezpechennia (Software engineering)"

But in the embassy, they tell not to come without approval from Anabin.
Does anyone know how to find the same "Software engineering" in any Ukrainian university?

Comment: This question belongs to Expatriates Stack Exchange. They are more likely able to help you.

Comment: I would suggest that you need to pay for evaluation of your degree by ZAB. See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11540/13223 for more details.

Comment: We're you able to solve this problem? I have the exact same degree and two years later it's not on Anabin.