# Education and work experience sync for Germany job seeker visa

Tags: visa, germany, immigration, job-hunting, education

I'm exploring options to apply for German job seeker visa and stuck with below question.

I've a graduate degree of Bachelor of Technology in Electronics and Communication stream. Currently, I'm working in IT domain.

What are the chances of my visa approval if my educational assessment isn't in par with work experience. I've seen few posts on internet where people mentioning about this criteria being the main root cause for their visa rejection.

Do they accept Electronics and Communication engineering degree okay for an IT job? I agree Mechanical, Chemical and Civil engineering degrees aren't close to IT but I feel ECE is bit closer compared to others.

Has someone's visa got accepted with this criteria?

Comment: I am a Bachelor of Technology in Mechanical Engineering in 2006 and I have more than 13 years of experience in SAP Plant Maintenance. At present I am working as a Senior Consultant in Deloitte from 23 Sep 2019 to till date. I would like to apply for Germany Job Seeker Visa and would like to know the chances to get success. Can anyone help me to understand since my education and work experience is not sync. Expecting responses asap. Thanks & regards, Vishnu.

Comment: Please see the relevant answer here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11511/13223

Answer (score 2):

It depends how far away are related  your degree and your laboral experience...
I mean e.g. if you are a Hardware Electronic developer but have been doing Embedded Software for years, then they probably wont take you to Hardware again...

So It can be difficult, but for sure not impossible to find a company that consider your experience more than your degree... (the most important thing they will need to be sure is:  you have theory/university-background supporting what you are doing)

I can tell you based on my own experience: I have a Electronic ing. degree  and I work with IT... have colleagues from almost similar branches like mechatronic but we have people with physics, mathematics and informatic background too...

In your case apply!!! You have a good chance!!