# Non-regulated job in Germany - Regular Work Permit for IT Specialists

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, eu, blue-card

In my ZAB certificate, it was mentioned that my foreign degree was not equivalent to a German bachelor's degree ruling me out from getting a Blue card. It was also mentioned that my foreign degree offers employment opportunities to non-regulated professions in my ZAB certificate. I did not find the IT/Software positions on the database of regulated professions in Germany, and I also found links that "IT Specialist" jobs do not require a degree.

How can I get a regular work permit on these conditions? What about rules on Federal Employment Agency? Am I only allowed to apply at job postings at their [site](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/)? Do you know other important things that needed to be considered?

Comment: There is indeed information claiming that you can work as an IT specialist without the equivalent degree. In any case I guess you can directly contact IT companies that might hire you and see what they say. I don't think it makes sense for you to only be able to apply for jobs on one official website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JIXiang. Are you also familiar with other requirements needed by companies to employ foreigners? I learned from others that most companies opt for EU Blue card as it expedites the hiring process. I'm not really sure if it has something to do with Bundesagentur für Arbeit, and if the jobs listed there are somewhat "ready to fill jobs" for people without EU Blue cards

Comment: Please see my answer for the related question: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11511/13223