# Do I need ANABIN certificate to apply for work visa to Germany?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, blue-card

I have got a job offer in Germany and I need to apply for a work visa/EU blue card. I have 4.5 years of experience in software development. I have completed my engineering from a well recognized university in Computer science engineering.
I have been reading about ANABIN. do I need this certificate for the work visa application or for applying for BLUE card?

NOTE* I have gone through the ANABIN database and I have found my university as well as my degree recognized. Do I still need the certificate?

Comment: You will need the degree, which they will check against the *ANABIN* Database.

Comment: Does this same condition apply for a regular work visa and not blue card?

Comment: Please also see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11511/13223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes or an equivalent type of certificate.

---

Source: **Visahandbuch** July 2018

- '**Blaue Karte EU**' Regulation

  - **II 1 a**: Precondition, Qualification, checking of certificate in *ANABIN* Database

Comment: Doesn't this say that "yes, but you already have it"?  The important thing is that the certificate must be in the ANABIN Database.

Comment: The instructions state that the reconised foreign certificates will be in the ANABIN database, which must be used as the only source.

Comment: This is only true for the Blue Card. The Work Visa doesn't require a university degree.

Comment: While this is true as per the regulations, seems like there may be exceptions and it's up to the authorities. I did not need to submit this during my application. Also, my degree was listed as H+ on the Anabin database and the degree was not relevant to my profession. I still got a blue card.

Comment: @WinstonJude Late 2021 (the question and answer is from 2019), the process has been simplified and more in line with the process in Germany where job experience is considered equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The **Blue Card** requires a recognised university degree or 5 years of experience in your field. I yet have to meet someone who managed to get their 5 years of experience recognised, but I didn't research the topic much.

The **work visa** does not require a university degree. I worked in Germany for 4 years as a software developer, and I don't have a university degree.

Comment: Does this apply to non-EU citizens and people from countries including places like India?

Comment: Of course. EU citizens do not need a visa to work in Germany. The work visa requirements are the same for everyone as far as I know.

Comment: I emailed the consulate in Germany and they said I wont be eligible. Strange! I have a degree. Though my university is recognized as H+, the degree is unfortunately only "conditionally comparable". I am applying for an Employment visa. Hope they are wrong

Comment: Update to the above comment: I applied anyway even though they said that I won't be eligible. I had a ZAV letter and I was granted a visa in just 2 days.

Comment: Nicolas, for the Blue Card in Germany, 5 years of experience in the field is not accepted as an option. For the residence permit for the purpose of employment indeed the university degree is not mandatory, but the vocational degree is (or, alternatively, several years of working experience). See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/21060/13223 and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11511/13223 for details.