# Can ASIIN (AQANIE) certificate be a replacement for ANABIN to get blue card in Germany?

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, blue-card, europe

I have got a job offer in Germany and I need to apply for a work visa/EU blue card. My university has H+/- status on the ANABIN website. I applied to get the equivalence certificate from the ZAB but unfortunately, it's taking much more time than I expected.
Knowing that my university is having an [AQANIE Accreditation certificate from ASIIN](http://www.asiin-ev.de/pages/de/asiin/akkreditierung-studiengaenge/akkreditierte-studiengaenge.php?id=7211), can I use it as a replacement for ANABIN to get the blue card?

PS: I got the idea of using an equivalent type of certificate from this [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/17458/24096) by [Mark Johnson](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/17166/mark-johnson), but I was not able to find the official document confirming that I can use ASIIN as a replacement.

Comment: Doesn't Mark's other answer suggest exactly the opposite, namely that only ANABIN can be used? I am a bit confused.

Comment: he said "Short answer: Yes or an equivalent type of certificate." for that i want to know if ASIIN can be considered as an equivalent type of certificate

Comment: True, but the quote only mention ANABIN and then in a comment he wrote "The instructions state that the reconised foreign certificates will be in the ANABIN database, which must be used as the only source." Note that Mark also has a history of confusing or downright incorrect answers. Maybe someone else will be able to provide a clearer answer but until then I wouldn't put much faith in that possibility.