# Germany Work Permit and German Master Degree Question

Tags: working-visas, germany

I had a BBA degree and one year experience working as the data analytics back in my home country, however, recently I just attend the MBA degree in Germany.

I will look for Data (IT-oriented) job after graduation.

The resident work permit and EU Blue Card is something I'm not really sure of.

**I have heard  that you need to work with the job that relevant to your degree in order to obtain work permit.**

In my case, the MBA may be not relevant to Data job that I expected to have.  Also, which permit should I apply for? German resident visa or EU Blue card?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that you don't need a degree to work as an "IT specialist" in Germany? What exactly classifies as "IT specialist" in this context?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/is-it-true-that-you-dont-need-a-degree-to-work-as-an-it-specialist-in-germany)

Answer (score 1):

The visa you apply for essentially depends on the type of job offer you have. If you:

- want to work in Germany in general employment (ie. a job that does not require you to be highly skilled or highly educated), you will need to apply for a German residence permit for the purpose of general employment (essentially a German work visa and German work permit). You will only be eligible if the position cannot be filled by a worker from the EU/EEA or Switzerland. You will need to have a vocational qualification and a firm offer of a job in Germany; you will need to show both evidence of your qualification and an employment contract or letter of intent in your application.
- hold a recognised university degree and have sufficient funds to support you during your stay, you can apply for a six-month residence permit to look for work, known as the jobseeker’s visa. You are not permitted, however, to undertake any work in Germany while looking.
- want to apply for an EU Blue Card in Germany you need a university degree from a German university or equivalent from a foreign university and a guaranteed job in Germany with an income of EUR 50,800 EUR (EUR 39,624 in shortage occupations).
- fit the highly skilled category (plus earning more than EUR 84,600) you can apply for a settlement permit, entitling you ­– and your family members – to live and work in Germany indefinitely.

Source: https://www.expatica.com/de/employment/employment-law/work-in-germany-getting-a-german-work-permit-100900/