# With Bachelor of Engineering Degree from India, Can I apply for Blue Card Visa in Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I have been recently offered a job in Berlin and am looking for starting my Visa process.

I have `Bachelor of Engineering` degree in `Computer Science` from `India`(VTU University).

I am not sure what sort of work Visa I should apply for.

I was going through the Germany visa requirements and it mentions:

> he or she has a German or an accredited foreign or a university degree that is comparable to a German one.

1. So, with the above-said degree, can I apply for a `blue-card` Visa. The other requirements (work salary) is fulfilled.

If not, what is the suitable work Visa category I should apply for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make at least 53600€ (in 2019) per year (before taxes). If there is a shortage of skilled workers in your field, you must make at least 41808€ (in 2019) per year. As a computer scientist, you qualify either way (although you *should* earn more than 53600€/year in Berlin).

However, for a Blue Card, your degree must be recognised in Germany. You can look at the [Anabin database](https://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/hochschulabschluesse.html).

For the residence permits other than Blue Card, please see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11511/13223.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what sort of job you got the contract for ? If it's IT related then you can directly apply for EU BLUE CARD considering that you have met the salary criteria. Recently I went through the same conditions and now they have granted me type D visa.

Comment: I have a job as a software engineer in berlin.

Comment: Then you are eligible for the blue card. I submitted the documents specified for the job seeker visa. As I am from Nepal the case might be different you can call the Embassy for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If the job you are applying for, corresponds to the degree you have (i.e. they match)

- then you can apply for a Blue Card

assuming that the other conditions are also fulfilled.

Otherwise you must apply for a normal work visa and based on your qualifications (practical experience), then a determination will be maded if this conforms to a **highly qualified employment** that is needed.

---

Based on the wording of [§ 19a AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__19a.html) ([English text](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0364))

> 1) A foreigner shall be granted an EU Blue Card pursuant to Council Directive 2009/50/EC of 25 May 2009 on the conditions of entry and residence of third-country nationals **for the purpose of highly qualified employment** (OJ L 155,18.6.2009, p. 17) **for the purpose of employment commensurate with his qualification**, if
>   ...
>   a)  holds a German or a foreign higher education qualification which is recognised or otherwise comparable to a German higher education qualification or

the degree must match the employment.