# Eligible for German work visa with "conditionally comparable" degree?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, blue-card, indian-citizens

I have been offered the role of “Software developer” but my degree currently is a Bachelor of Arts (Major in Psychology, Journalism and English).  As far as the officials told me, I will only need a recognized degree and it does not need to be related to my profession.

As per anabin, my university is currently recognized in Germany (Bangalore University as H+). However, my degree is "conditionally comparable" only.

I am applying for a regular work/employment visa and not a Blue Card. I currently reside in India. The salary being offered is also above 41,000 EUR.

I would like to know what my chances are and what I can do to improve it. Would requesting a ZAV letter from my employer help?

Comment: As an IT professional you should either get a visa on the grounds of §2 or §4 [BeschV](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beschv_2013/). The former visa is definitely the better one. I'm not from India and the conditions also depend on intergovernmental agreements - definitely ask the embassy and the employer. Triple check if you are qualified for a Blue Card because having that is a major advantage.

Comment: When I inquired at the embassy they said it should not be an issue but when I emailed to confirm they said that I would not be eligible as I do not qualify as a highly-skilled worker. Moreover, my employer seems to be trying fro a ZAV pre-approval. So I'm guessing there is no definite answer, I'll just have to try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that you don't need a degree to work as an "IT specialist" in Germany? What exactly classifies as "IT specialist" in this context?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/is-it-true-that-you-dont-need-a-degree-to-work-as-an-it-specialist-in-germany)

Comment: Hi I am also in similar situation. Although my university show as H+ but my degree is under 3A which is conditionally comparable due to 3 years Degree. But I have 14 years of related experience in IT. I have a job offer from Germany with the high salary which far more than the required salary for Blue Card. will I be having a chance of getting Blue Card ?

Comment: @Ges01 It worked for me. Though I had only a few years of experience, it was still not an issue. I would advice you to stay positive and apply.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer this, I was granted a visa eventually.

Initially, when I mailed the embassy to inquire, I was told I had no chance of getting a visa. But when I applied, I surprisingly was approved.

This is what I did:

- I requested my employer for a ZAV pre-approval letter.
- I submitted my educational qualifications and the ZAV letter along with the visa application. Although my degree was only conditionally comparable, they considered the application. I also attached my post-graduate diploma certificate (But I'm not sure if this was considered). There was no detailed explanation on what grounds they granted me a visa.

This leaves me with only one conclusion that it depends on the authorities.

### Update as of late 2020:

So with the 6-month entry visa granted to me, I later applied for a residence permit and I was given the EU blue card.

I think it's also worth looking at this thread [Is it true that you don't need a degree to work as an "IT specialist" in Germany? What exactly classifies as "IT specialist" in this context?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/is-it-true-that-you-dont-need-a-degree-to-work-as-an-it-specialist-in-germany)

Comment: This does not depend on the visa official, it depends on the local authority in Germany. They send their decision to the visa official who then issues the visa.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks, I've updated it