# Work permit eligibility in Germany without degree but with more than 8 years of experience in Information Systems Engineering and Cybersecurity?

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card, skilled-migration, work-permit

I've been contacted by an organization for a senior role in cybersecurity domain, and the problem is I don't have any college degree, just an Associate Degree which is not recognized as a college degree in Germany, but I've solid 8+ years of experience in Systems Engineering and cybersecurity with Big 4 Audit Firms.

Can I still qualify for a Work Permit without blue card?

I am a non-EU citizen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that you don't need a degree to work as an "IT specialist" in Germany? What exactly classifies as "IT specialist" in this context?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/is-it-true-that-you-dont-need-a-degree-to-work-as-an-it-specialist-in-germany)

Comment: Your degree has nothing to do with a work permit. If you can get a work contract you can get a work permit.