# Work visa requirements for Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas

### I am in this situation:

- A IT company is interested to sponsor me work visa in Germany
- I am also interested to go there ( of course )
- I do not have bachelors degree
- I have 6 month intern + 6 month full time job experience in IT field
- I am confused how my visa will be processed

### About company

- IOT and Blockchain company
- Well established and in-profit business
- Have hired handful of developer from India and other countries too

### About me

- IT student ( thinking of joining some online bachelors class )
- 6 month web dev experience as intern
- six month as full-time blockchain development ( I will be working here while I wait for visa processing )

### My question

Everything else seems smooth. Only problem is, if I processed with this profile ( 1year of experience in IT and no bachelors degree ), will there be any chance that Germany embassy will refuse my visa ( I saw somewhere that at least 3 years of experience is must ) even though company is totally fine with it

Comment: It depends on what visa you want, and by which track. There are types for academics, there are types for professional experience, and there are types where the local labor office certifies that no domestic jobseeker is suitable.

Comment: Company is about to sponser me work visa.

Comment: There are different kinds of sponsorship. The company should get a lawyer in Germany to do it right.

Comment: see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/7079/13223